# Detail View of Split view controller doesnt changing its size in ios 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ipad

In my iPad application, i have used `UISplitViewController` where master view contains table view while detail view holds `UIViewController`. On button event detail view comes over master view, code is mentioned following. This code works fine on iPad 3.2 but not working on ios 4.2.

```
UIViewController *leftUIV = [appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];  
UIViewController *rightUIV = [appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];  
CGRect rectMaster = leftUIV.view.frame;  
CGRect rectDetail = rightUIV.view.frame;  
rectMaster.size.width = 0;
rectDetail.size.width = 1024;  
rectDetail.origin.x = 0;  
[leftUIV.view setFrame:rectMaster];  
[rightUIV.view setFrame:rectDetail];
```

Please help, How should I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got the answer on site [Click here](http://vimeo.com/13054813)

Thanks to - Alice Bevan and McGregor

Comment: Just a note: if you have problems with rotations on the detailScreen after presenting it as described in this solution here is a slight adaption to make transformations work correctly: Use a NavController as rootViewController of your application. If you hide the navBar you can add the splitView to the navController. If you now want to present the detailView in fullscreen just change the viewController of the NavController from the SplitView to the detailView.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do something unsupported. You can't resize the splits: the sizes are fixed.

If you wanted to temporarily show only the detail view in landscape mode, perhaps you could remove the split view from the view hierarchy and add just the detail view instead, then swap them back when you're done?

Comment: But actually it works fine over ipad 3.2 devices. Although removing split view is not good idea, i tried to present detail view modally but it also didnt work finally.

Comment: Actually removing split view and adding detail view in slightly different manner, we can present detail view in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your DetailViewController.m

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [self.view sizeToFit];

    NSLog(@"ROTATE - self.view.frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame)); 
}
```